# Where are the default Emmet settings in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, emmet

Where are the default Emmet settings in Visual Studio Code (v1.15.1)?

I'm looking for the file that makes Visual Studio Code expand the Emmet HTML abbreviation `!` into:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to workaround some problems that happened since [Visual Studio Code started being shipped with Emmet 2.0 by default](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/08/07/emmet-2.0).

Answer (score 3):

You can override it with [custom snippets](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/).

File *[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>):

```json
"emmet.extensionsPath": PATH_TO_YOUR_NEW_FOLDER_WITH_SNIPPETS
```

In this folder, create file `snippets.json`:

> Emmet 2.0: Custom Emmet snippets in HTML should be a valid abbreviation. For example: use `ul>li` instead of `<ul><li></li></ul>`.

> If you want to have just text and not markup in your snippet then use the `{}`notation:

> `{<ul><li></li></ul>}`

```json
{
    "variables": {
        "lang": "en"
    },
    "html": {
        "snippets": {
            "!": "!!!+html[lang=${lang}]>(head>meta[charset=UTF-8]+title{Document})+body"
        }
    }
}
```

[Visual Studio Code documentation: *"Using custom Emmet snippets"*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not asking about custom snippets, rather I'm looking for the Code file that contains Code's default emmet settings.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to specify what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: My question specifically asks for what I'm looking for -- the file that contains VS Code's default emmet settings.

Answer (score 3):

From [this Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/8aqo4k/where_is_emmet_snippetsjson_file_located/dx2o6e2):

> I'm not sure where they are located on your filesystem when Visual Studio Code is installed, but all the default HTML snippets are here:
>
> https://github.com/emmetio/snippets/blob/master/html.json

Answer (score 1):

You can find the default Emmet settings in the *defaultSettings.json* file.

However, it's easier to open Visual Studio Code, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type: "defaultSettings" to access this configuration file.

<sub>This directly answers your question, but it won't necessarily help you solve your problem.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Well, unfortunately you can't get the default Emmet settings, since the plugin is bundled with VS Code itself. You can view default Emmet files in editor's source code: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/emmet

As Peter Mortensen mentioned above, you can only add or customize Emmet snippets with extra file. It's explained in details here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Hope it satisfies your interest in this matter.