# Can I remove tags from the emmet HTML boilerplate in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

When I type `!` and hit enter in an .html file I get a nice boilerplate like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

My question is can I remove the tag:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

I know I can add my own snippets but I haven't found a way to change the default HTML boilerplate when I type `!`

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/apkrxd/edit_emmet_html_snippet/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the default Emmet settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019310/where-are-the-default-emmet-settings-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Not really or I may be missing something, but thank you, that shows me how to add custom snippets, I'm looking for the file that contains the HTML boilerplate code emmet produces when I type `!`

Comment: you can define user defined Emmet snippets, and such create your own `!` version by giving it a different prefix

Comment: Thank you, I have created my own snippet using a different prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can. But keep in mind that an update could overwrite this setting.

Open VSCode installation path and navigate to

.. `VS Code\resources\app\extensions\emmet\dist\node\emmetNodeMain.js`

just search and delete the next meta

```
meta[http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'][content='IE=edge']+
```

near the secuence:

```
doc:"html[lang=${lang}]>(head>meta[charset=${charset}]+meta[http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'][content='IE=edge']+meta:vp+title{${1:Document}})+body"
```

This path could be different from one version to other.