# VSCode Make Emmet use single quotes instead of double quotes in class names and ids

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

By default, Emmet in VSCode uses double quotes when expanding class names and IDs. For example, expanding

```
#bob.frank
```

creates

```
<div id="bob" class="frank"></div>
```

Is there a way to make Emmet use single quotes, e.g.

```
<div id='bob' class='frank'></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to add these lines into the `settings.json` file:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "svelte": "html",
    "typescript": "html",
    "javascriptreact": "html",
    "typescriptreact": "html",
    "html": {
        "attr_quotes": "single",
        "self_closing_tag": true,
    },
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "svelte": "html",
    "typescript": "html",
    "javascriptreact": "html",
    "typescriptreact": "html",
    //"javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
```

*(Of course, you only need to include languages that you are actually using. For eg, if you are not using [svelte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0v5WcrU_vM&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hlbrVO_2QFVqVPhlZmz7tO&index=18) (why not??) or typescript then leave 'em out)*

**Extra:**

If you are also wondering how to use the Tab key to expand Emmet abbreviations, add this line also:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

So: for each language that you use Emmet with, you want to map that language type to `"html"`, and then in the `"html"` key, tell it to use `"attr_quotes": "single"`

**Where Do I Make This Change?**

Depending on your platform, the user settings file (`settings.json`) is located here:

```
Windows: %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
macOS  : $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
Linux  : $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

ALTERNATE method to open the settings.json file inside VSCode:

a. Ctrl + , (comma) to open Settings
b. Workbench
c. Settings Editor
e. In the search box at top, type `emmet.`
f. On the left, click Workbench and then Appearance
g. Click the link to right: Edit in settings.json

References:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/06/custom-emmet-snippets-vscode/

[Where are the default Emmet settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019310/where-are-the-default-emmet-settings-in-visual-studio-code)

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32496

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/06/custom-emmet-snippets-vscode/

https://sudolabs.io/blog/tips-to-use-vscode-more-efficiently

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add that, if you want to use single quotes around attribute values in JSX/TSX while still want to keep the existing behavior (e.g. double quotes around attribute values) for `.html` files, you can use:

```json
{
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascriptreact": "xml",
    "typescriptreact": "xml"
  },
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "xml": {
      "attr_quotes": "single"
    }
  }
}
```

References:

- [Emmet abbreviations in other file types](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-abbreviations-in-other-file-types)
- [syntaxProfiles.json](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/)

Comment: Thanks for adding this note, but I'm not sure what you mean - what is the significance of "xml", what does that effect (other than actual xml). When would someone use this, can you provide a couple of examples? What existing behavior would one preserve (for example). *Thanks!*

Comment: @cssyphus For example, if I want to use double quotes for html files while using single quotes for jsx/tsx files, then this setting would come in handy.

Comment: @cssyphus Or there're other customizations made for the html profile, and you don't want jsx/tsx files to use them.

Answer (score 2):

In VSCode, to autocomplete attributes with single/double quotes, search following property in `File > Preferences > Settings` based on file types and update drop-down values to either `single` or `double`.

1. For HTML files: `html.completion.attributeDefaultValue`
2. For JavaScript files: `javascript.preferences.quoteStyle`
3. For TypeScript files: `typescript.preferences.quoteStyle`

Comment: this is an answer to the wrong question. this question is about emmet- not manually-typed attributes.

Comment: But... its was excatly what I was looking for =) ps. I didnt read the question either

Answer (score 0):

If you are using prettier, search for single quotes in settings and just check
Prettier: Jsx Single Quote