# VS Code, HTML autocomplete, single quotes instead of double quotes

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In VS code, typing `img` then hitting **tab** gives `<img src="" alt="">`

I would like it to autocomplete with single quotes, i.e. `<img src='' alt=''>`

I changed the setting **html.completion.attributeDefaultValue** from doublequotes to singlequotes but this has not had the desired effect.

The **html.completion.attributeDefaultValue** setting seems to only have an impact if you have `<img src`, and then hit tab, in which case it gives `<img src=''`

Does anyone know if there is a setting which can be changed which would allow `img` to autocomplete with single quotes directly?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749881/vscode-make-emmet-use-single-quotes-instead-of-double-quotes-in-class-names-and

Answer (score 2):

For things like that most people, me included, use the extension prettier.
After installing it, create a ".prettierrc" file in your projects root and add  the following to it.

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used prettier too, but couldn't make it work with the ".prettierrc" file when writing JSX, but if you go to your extension settings and scroll down a bit you will find **"Prettier: Jsx Single Quote"** with a checkbox, just turn that one on and it will work. Also at the very bottom of the setting is a second checkbox for **"Prettier: Single Quote".**

**EDIT:** I still had some issues with the quotes even after trying this, solved it again by checking on the settings for all format files, since I was editing a JS and not a "JSX" file it had a separate setting.

[Settings window containing "quote" on the search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGh14.png)

Just type **"quote"** on the search bar of the settings window and you can find all the related rules for all file formats. hope this helps someone :)